# Vue js - multiple components with each a different initial selected value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm creating a multiselect in Vue js, but wat i dont understand is how can i get multiple instance of the component with each a different initial selected value (v-model). Every component is getting the same initial value because of the selected data on the parent. Should i also use props here instead of v-model? or should i move the data object from the parent to the component itself?

**Wat i want**

Component one should have initial select "{ id: "0", text: "One"}" and 
Component two should have initial select "{ id: "1", text: "Two"}"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
</head>
<body>

<div id="app">
  <multi-select v-model="selected" :options='[{ id: "0", text: "One"}, { id: "1", text: "Two"}'></multi-select>
  <multi-select v-model="selected" :options='[{ id: "0", text: "One"}, { id: "1", text: "Two"}'></multi-select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script>

  Vue.component("multi-select", {

      props: ["options", "value"],

      template: `
        <div>
          <div v-for="option in selectedOption">{{ option.text }}</div>
          <hr>
          <div v-for="option in options">{{ option.text }}</div>
        </div>
      `,

      computed: {
        selectedOption() {
          return this.value;
        }
      }
  });

  new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
      selected: [{ id: "0", text: "One"}],
    }
  })

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass index as props and your child component can use this index to decide the default value.

```
v-bind:index="0"
v-bind:index="1"
```

Answer (score 1):

v-model means the selected value, pay attention that you are assigning both multiselects
to the same variable.

a possible solution is creating another variable, lets say `selector2` and `selector1`

and assigning your v-model accordingly.

```
data: {
      selected1: [{ id: "0", text: "One"}],
      selected2: [{ id: "1", text: "Two"}],
    }
```

and on assignment

```
<div id="app">
  <multi-select v-model="selected1" :options='[{ id: "0", text: "One"}, { id: "1", text: "Two"}'></multi-select>
  <multi-select v-model="selected2" :options='[{ id: "0", text: "One"}, { id: "1", text: "Two"}'></multi-select>
</div>
```